# Slack slash command works sometimes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, slack

We have a Slack slash command that executes a Lambda (written in node) in AWS. The Lambda calls an internal service we have and returns JSON. It often takes multiple executions to get the slash command to work. The caller gets the below message:

> Darn - that slash command didn't work. If you see this message more than once we suggest you contact "name".

We ran a bash sript that calls the lambda once a minute for 12 hours. The average duration of the calls was about 1.5 seconds, well below the slash command expectation that a response will be returned in 3 seconds. Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: Calling the function once a minute for 12 hours does not account for "cold starts".  It would make sense that your function only succeeds after a few tries if it takes a long time to set up.  If the issue is the cold start, one thing you can try is increasing the memory size.  Also, check if you have any code outside of your handler that could be increasing this time.  
If not, check the cloudwatch logs for your function.  Something could be failing conditionally inside your function

Comment: @JonathanSeed the cold start is the leading candidate at this point. If you enter that as an answer I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the timeout over 3 secs though your estimated run time is around 1.5 seconds.

Also, it is to be noted that AWS Lambda limits the total concurrent executions across all functions within a given region to 100 (default limit which can increased on request)

Comment: Slack only allows 3 seconds for a response, so this won’t work if the function is taking that long to run.